# Make squad open to public

Tags: ps3, battlefield-4

How do I make squad open to public? I have a ps3 and it says in squad settings friends only. But if you try to change it, it won't even go to it. Just skips it. Does anyone know? I've been looking on google but can't get a answer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the team setup options on the escape menu. Find your squad and if you're the squad leader you can make it public.